# Reset selected fields of EntitySpaces query

Tags: entityspaces

EntitySpaces is used in a project I'm currently working on. Since EntitySpaces documentation is scarce and all EntitySpaces knowledge left the company I'm getting along with what I can.

Question: How do I reset the selected fields on a query object, so I can reuse it with the former defined joins and where clause?

Answer (score 1):

You really need to create a new query, EntitySpaces Queries are single use only. Also, the full documentation is installed when you install the entirely free version from [CNET's download.com](http://download.cnet.com/1770-20_4-0.html?query=entityspaces&platformSelect=Windows&tag=srch&searchtype=downloads&filterName=platform=Windows&filter=platform=Windows), a link is available from the [EntitySpaces website on the home page](http://www.entityspaces.net/www.entityspaces.net/Portal/Default.aspx.html). Once you get to download.com use the "link" under the download button not the download button itself. You get the full source, everything, it's fantastic, you can install ES2012 and it will not interfere with older non 2012 versions. The full help is installed locally, see your EntitySpaces 2012 menu after installation.

- Mike Griffin